# Nodejs: How to reverse proxy + TLS certificates with Caddy (Cloudflare)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, cloudflare, caddy

this is my first time deploying `nodejs` from `localhost` to the live server. I am using `aapanel` for my live server.

Here is the relevant code in `node server.js` file:

```
const hostname = 'localhost';
// const hostname = 'www.thespacebar.io';

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Here is my `pm2` settings:
[image]

I am unable to open my `nodejs` app with GET `https://www.thespacebar.io:8080`, but it works for GET `http://www.thespacebar.io:8080`

GET  `https://www.thespacebar.io:8080` does not work with error:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Anyone know what I did wrong?

**EDIT**: I have installed `Caddy` and setup the `Caddyfile` in `/etc/caddy` like this:

```
# The Caddyfile is an easy way to configure your Caddy web server.
#
# Unless the file starts with a global options block, the first
# uncommented line is always the address of your site.
#
# To use your own domain name (with automatic HTTPS), first make
# sure your domain's A/AAAA DNS records are properly pointed to
# this machine's public IP, then replace ":80" below with your
# domain name.

import ./thespacebar.io

:80 {
        # Set this path to your site's directory.
        root * /usr/share/caddy

        # Enable the static file server.
        file_server

        # Another common task is to set up a reverse proxy:
        # reverse_proxy localhost:8080

        # Or serve a PHP site through php-fpm:
        # php_fastcgi localhost:9000
}

# Refer to the Caddy docs for more information:
# https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile
```

and created the adjacent file `thespacebar.io`:

```
thespacebar.io {
  reverse_proxy localhost:8080
}
```

but when I visit `https://thespacebar.io/`, I end up at `index.html` instead of the JSON `{ message: "Welcome to bezkoder application." }`
and **POST** `http://www.thespacebar.io/api/verification/callback` with `body param` `verify_token:abcde` is supposed to show the JSON:

```
{
    "message": "Callback called successfully."
}
```

instead of `404 Not Found`

**EDIT 2**: I have removed the portion:

```
# :80 {
        # Set this path to your site's directory.
#       root * /usr/share/caddy

        # Enable the static file server.
#       file_server

        # Another common task is to set up a reverse proxy:
        # reverse_proxy localhost:8080

        # Or serve a PHP site through php-fpm:
        # php_fastcgi localhost:9000
# }

# Refer to the Caddy docs for more information:
# https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile
```

from `etc/caddy/Caddyfile`

but when I run `caddy run Caddyfile` and `caddy reload Caddyfile`, I am getting this error:

```
[root@vultrguest caddy]# caddy run Caddyfile
2022/12/02 08:11:44.132 INFO    using adjacent Caddyfile
2022/12/02 08:11:44.132 WARN    Caddyfile input is not formatted; run the 'caddy fmt' command to fix inconsistencies    {"adapter": "caddyfile", "file": "Caddyfile", "line": 12}
2022/12/02 08:11:44.133 INFO    admin   admin endpoint started  {"address": "localhost:2019", "enforce_origin": false, "origins": ["//localhost:2019", "//[::1]:2019", "//127.0.0.1:2019"]}
2022/12/02 08:11:44.133 INFO    http    server is listening only on the HTTPS port but has no TLS connection policies; adding one to enable TLS {"server_name": "srv0", "https_port": 443}
2022/12/02 08:11:44.133 INFO    http    enabling automatic HTTP->HTTPS redirects        {"server_name": "srv0"}
2022/12/02 08:11:44.133 INFO    tls.cache.maintenance   started background certificate maintenance      {"cache": "0xc000151030"}
2022/12/02 08:11:44.133 INFO    tls.cache.maintenance   stopped background certificate maintenance      {"cache": "0xc000151030"}
Error: loading initial config: loading new config: http app module: start: listening on :80: listen tcp :80: bind: address already in use
[root@vultrguest caddy]# caddy reload Caddyfile
2022/12/02 08:11:49.875 INFO    using adjacent Caddyfile
2022/12/02 08:11:49.876 WARN    Caddyfile input is not formatted; run the 'caddy fmt' command to fix inconsistencies    {"adapter": "caddyfile", "file": "Caddyfile", "line": 12}
Error: sending configuration to instance: performing request: Post "http://localhost:2019/load": dial tcp [::1]:2019: connect: connection refused
[root@vultrguest caddy]#
```

If I run **GET** `http://www.thespacebar.io:8080` I get:

```
Web server is down Error code 521
Visit cloudflare.com for more information.
2022-12-02 08:22:13 UTC
You
```

**EDIT3:** The site I am trying to setup reverse proxy is using cloudflare, so I have modified my `Caddyfile` to:

```
# The Caddyfile is an easy way to configure your Caddy web server.
#
# Unless the file starts with a global options block, the first
# uncommented line is always the address of your site.
#
# To use your own domain name (with automatic HTTPS), first make
# sure your domain's A/AAAA DNS records are properly pointed to
# this machine's public IP, then replace ":80" below with your
# domain name.

# import ./thespacebar.io

# cloudflare 
(cf) {
    tls {
        resolvers 1.1.1.1
        dns cloudflare [cf-token-goes-here]
    }
}

but when I run `caddy run Caddyfile`, I got this error:
`Error: adapting config using caddyfile: parsing caddyfile tokens for 'tls': Caddyfile:17 - Error during parsing: getting module named 'dns.providers.cloudflare': module not registered: dns.providers.cloudflare`

thespacebar.io {
  import cf
  reverse_proxy localhost:8080
}
```

but when I goto `cd /etc/caddy` and `caddy run Caddyfile` I get the error:

`Error: adapting config using caddyfile: parsing caddyfile tokens for 'tls': Caddyfile:17 - Error during parsing: getting module named 'dns.providers.cloudflare': module not registered: dns.providers.cloudflare`

all the tutorials for adding this `module (dns.providers.cloudflare)` are for `xcaddy` and not `caddy`, how do I add this module for `caddy`?

Comment: perhaps you've misconfigured caddy2 - without seeing how you've configured caddy2, how can we know what you did wrong (have you even set up caddyserver?)

Comment: actually I have not written any command for caddy2 yet, this is just the default response I get, do you mind showing a simple example of how the command looks like?

Comment: command? what command? I thought you wanted to set up caddyserver

Answer (score 0):

Caddy is simple to setup as a reverse proxy, and it gets letsencrypt SSL certs for you with minimal fuss

```
{
    email example@email.com
}
thespacebar.io {
     reverse_proxy localhost:8080
}
```

I see you've posted an update - the one thing I would remove is

```
:80 {
  .....
}
```

If you read the text you posted it does say to replace :80 with your domain (but don't add :80 or caddy won't do the certificate for the domain)

I also see you haven't set up a global section with an email address - I'm fairly sure that needs to be there (don't quote me on that) for letsencrypt to work - at least it used to when I first started using caddy

Answer (score 0):

here is some pseudo code for a generic caddyfile for caddy v2
***for the code below replace `"\*"` with `"*"`  `"\"` is used below to escape `"/*"` in the markdown***

this code will add basic security headers and cors to the response
it will proxy pass thru to a process on localhost port 9883
if you have a dns record for your server it will set up the letsencrypt certs for you and renew them when required
see caddy snippets https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/concepts#snippets

```
# begin common code block snippet to be imported into the server block, 
# for example here we set common security headers
# see the markdown escape comment above for "/\*" should be "/*"
(common) {
    header /\* {
        -Server
        -X-Powered-By
        +X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none
        +X-Frame-Options DENY
        +X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
        +Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000 includeSubDomains preload"
        +Referrer-Policy no-referrer
        }
}
# cors snippet
(cors) { 
    @cors_preflight method OPTIONS
# "{args.0}" is an input value used when calling the snippet
  
    @cors header Origin "{args.0}"  
        handle @cors_preflight {
            header Access-Control-Allow-Origin  "{args.0}"
            header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
            header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
            header Access-Control-Max-Age "3600"
            respond "" 204
    }
}

# main server block
# dns record for server is myserver.edu
myserver.edu { 

# import common sec headers snippet
    import common   
# import cors snippet passing server name parameter, wildcard cors poor sec
    import cors myserver.edu  

# proxy redirect see handle_path directive 
# https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/handle_path
# see the markdown escape comment above for "/\*" should be "/*"
    handle_path /somepath/\* {
        reverse_proxy localhost:9883 {
            header_up X-Real-IP {remote_host}
            # caddy will add X-Forwarded-For for you so not need this one
            #header_up X-Forwarded-For {remote_host}
            header_down Content-Security-Policy "media-src blob:"
            }
        }

}
```